# Printing control characters using escaped notation

Tags: c

I need help understanding what are they really asking here.
I have written part of the program already.
Do I have to print the decimal value for the newline character and the tab character?
Why I can't get 10 pair per line all the time? Sometimes I get 10 pairs and another times not.

The assignment was:

> Write a program that reads input as a stream of characters until
>   encountering EOF. Have the program print each input character and its
>   ASCII decimal value.
>
> Note that characters preceding the space character in the ASCII
>   sequence are nonprinting characters. Treat them specially. If the
>   nonprinting character is a newline or tab, print \n or \t,
>   respectively. Otherwise, use control-character notation. For instance,
>   ASCII 1 is Ctrl+A, which can be displayed as ^A. Note that the ASCII
>   value for A is the value for Ctrl+A plus 64. A similar relation holds
>   for the other nonprinting characters. Print 10 pairs per line, except
>   start a fresh line each time a newline character is encountered.

This is what I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
    int ch;
    int i=0;

    printf("Please enter some characters.\n\n");

    while((ch=getchar()) != EOF)
    {
    if((i%10) == 0)
        printf("\n");

    if (ch == '\n')
        printf( "\n\\n ");
    else if (ch == '\t')
        printf("\\t %d ", ch);
    else if (ch < ' ')
        printf("^%c %d  ", ch+64, ch);
    else
        printf("%c %d  ",ch, ch);

    i = i+1;
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/  you're going to process a binary file.

Comment: What is your question? It looks like all you're missing is the distinction between printables and non-printables.

Comment: The program runs, but I not sure if it is working right.

Answer (score 3):

What they're asking for sounds very clear; here is some pseudo-code:

```
if (ch == '\n') print "\n %d", ch;
else if (ch == '\t') print "\t %d", ch;
else if (ch < ' ') { print "^"; print "%c %d", ch+'A', ch; }
else print "%c %d",ch, ch;
```

This is exclusive of formatting needed to make it look right; your code already has some formatting.

Answer (score 2):

ASCII 0-31 are non-printing characters. Their respective control-character notations can be found at [the ASCII Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters) in the [b] column.

You will want to print the control-character notation for these characters, with the exception of 9 and 10, for which you will print `\t` and `\n` (backslash-t and backslash-n), respectively.

Another thing about your loop

```
if((i%10==0) || (ch == '\n'))
printf("\n");
```

These should be two separate statements. Make sure to escape your backslashes with an extra backslash beforehand as `printf("\\n");` will actually print `"\n"` (backslash-n) whereas `printf("\n")` will just print an actual line feed, which I'm almost certain is not what your instructor is asking for here, except after each ten entries.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Wikipedia pages about [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), the [caret notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) (which is similar to control notation). I don't want to post the solution here. :D